# jQuery $.get changes the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I write

```
$.get("http://localhost/bookstore/public/actualizar_paginas/local/11/46", function(data){});
```

Mysteriously, when I debug I discover that the query is made to the following url:

```
http://localhost/actualizar_paginas/local/11/46
```

So the code doesn't work.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: seems like you have a url rewrite logic somewhere. Check you code.

Comment: What happens when you visit that URL directly?

Comment: How are you debugging? Inside the script or using a debugging proxy or in the service you are calling. I don't think JQuery is changing the url. It's somewhere in the transport.

Comment: Are you redirecting to the second URL from the server?

Comment: I debug with a console.log of the url. If I visit the changed url directly it gives a 404 error. I'm not redirecting.

Comment: But the source code of the page have the right url.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using console.log, is the firefox default debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it. A stupid bug with Laravel URLs.
I actually wrote:

```
http://localhost/bookstore/public/actualizar_paginas/local/11/46/
```

And it get fixed if I write:

```
http://localhost/bookstore/public/actualizar_paginas/local/11/46
```

It looks like that the debugger of firefox was changing the url but it didn't affect the page at all.

Thank you.